# Not sure how to deploy some Java code

Tags: java, log4j

I've been working really hard to load log4j logs into LogStash ([as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947786/unable-to-get-log4j-socketappender-working)). Unfortunately, I learned that there is [a bug](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-2055) associated with the approach I was trying to use. This has made me consider alternative approaches. This lead me to the [log4j-jsonevent-layout](https://github.com/logstash/log4j-jsonevent-layout).

I'm not very familiar with Java. I've downloaded the code from Git hub. I can successfully make the project in IntelliJ. However, I'm now stuck. I see two .class files. However, I do not see a .jar file or anything like that. From my understanding, I can't just copy and paste .class files. So, I'm not sure how to deploy this utility.

Beyond that, I believe I just need to update my log4j2.xml file to something like this:

```
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Appenders>
      <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingFile" fileName="/logs/current.log"
                               filePattern="/logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/server-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">
        <layout class="net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV1" />
        <Policies>
          <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="4" modulate="true"/>
          <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/>
        </Policies>
      </RollingRandomAccessFile>
      <Async name="AsyncFile">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
      </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.myCompany" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="AsyncFile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="AsyncFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I feel like I'm close. If I can just figure out a) what I need to deploy and b) where to deploy it to. I think it'll work. Any help is significantly appreciated. A big proactive 'Thank you' to anyone in the Java community that can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Maven to build your project, just add the project as a dependency.

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cnet.logstash.log4j

Otherwise download the jars manually from the central repository, and add them to your classpath.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I downloaded the .jar to /home/ubuntu on my machine. I used nano /etc/environment and added CLASSPATH="/home/ubuntu" to the file. I restarted my app that is using log4j. Unfortunately, its still not using the json_event format. What would cause this? Am I missing something? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: No. Oddly when I do "echo CLASSPATH" from the command-line, I do not see the see the value I entered. I feel dumb. I'm a nube to Ubuntu (Linux) and Java. I might be biting off more than I can chew. But I feel so close.

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing this is a classpath issue.  Are you running your program on a server, or from the command line?

Comment: I'm running the program from the command-line. It's a server. I've logged into that machine and I ran sudo su. So, it shouldn't be permission related.

Comment: Any particular server (tomcat,jetty,...) , or is it something you wrote yourself?

Comment: Its just an ubuntu machine running on Amazon EC2.

Comment: When you say you 'added CLASSPATH="/HOME/ubuntu" to the file'. Which file are you referring to?

Comment: try putting 'export CLASSPATH="/home/ubuntu"'  Also, the jar files you downloaded must be in that directory.

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me. I think I confirmed /home/ubuntu to my  CLASSPATH. I ran echo $CLASSPATH from my command-line. I see the /home/ubuntu there. However, its still not working :(